# jQuery mobile scrolling/page cut off issue on multi page template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Having this strange issue where page/screen is being cut off.

Seems to happen when you click into this screen below (which is shorter) then click back and go into another longer screen. The scrollbar doesn't appear so the page is cut off. Testing in Chrome v36 & iOS Safari.

http://onegreenthing.net/sunsuper/RetirementModeller/Forecast.html#retirement-age

Any ideas?

PS: Resize window so it's mobile like width (e.g. 400px wide)

Answer (score 0):

```
.the-thing:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

Smells like psuedo-vertical-centering that isn't recalculated to vanish appropriately if the page's content is naturally taller than the viewport.

Post-comment update - try this:

```
if( $(document).height() >  $(window).height() ) {
  $(".the-thing").remove();
}
```

Post-comment#2 - your main container element has this css (for id='retirement-age'):

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

if I pull up my window shorter than 300 - I get the no-scroll thing - not buggy - that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, changed to below and still had same problem 
`.the-thing {
 height: 10px;
}`

Comment: Dude! hax.  Cheap hax :)  But I'll raise your cheap hax by dynamic hax.

if( $(document).height() >  $(window).height() ) {
  $(".the-thing").remove();
}

it's cheap, fast & dirty.  If the document is taller than the window, obliterate the thing :)

Comment: Thanks again, yeah whole thing is bit of hax! Removed image.the-thing from the mark up completely and still didn't fix the problem. It looks like the variable height of the screens is the issue. As soon as I go into shorter screen then the longer screen get chop off (i.e. no ability to scroll).

Comment: You could take it in the other direction... (1) use jQuery to HIDE the thing. (2) if the doc is >= the window height, do nothing. (3) if the document is < window height, show the-thing.  You should get natural scrolls and then, on the occasional super-short page, it vertically centers nicely.  If you don't care about that, total removal is the best bet. --- I think you should check your CSS pretty hard though mate.  See my original answer for update(s).

Answer (score 0):

Ok rookie error :( ..there was page with duplicate id, removed it and fixed the issue.